# Generate excel column name from index

Tags: code-golf, conversion

This one comes from a real life problem. We solved it, of course, but it keeps feeling like it could have be done better, that it's too lengthy and roundabout solution. However none of my colleagues can think of a more succinct way of writing it. Hence I present it as code-golf.

The goal is to convert a nonnegative integer into a string the same way Excel presents its column headers. Thus:

```
0 -> A
1 -> B
...
25 -> Z
26 -> AA
27 -> AB
...
51 -> AZ
52 -> BA
...
16,383 -> XFD
```

It has to work **at least** up to 16,383, but beyond is acceptable too (no bonus points though). I'm looking forward most to the C# solution, but, as per traditions of code-golf, any real programming language is welcome.

Comment: Are you sure that 16383 should be XFD? What do you get for 676 and 702?

Comment: Well, that's what Excel shows, and I found it on the web that it has 16384 columns. I'll test it tomorrow with our (known to work) code (is late night right now where I live).

Comment: Also, testing with Excel itself reveals that 676=ZA and 702=AAA.

Comment: The reason I ask is that I wrote some straightforward base-26 code, got results which fit yours precisely, but broke on 676 and 702.

Comment: Yup. It's not Base-26. That's the problem. ;)

Comment: If your numbering started from 1 it would be base-27 (A-Z and the empty string representing the 0), I think. As it is, the rightmost column has 26 possible values and the rest have 27. Which is awkward.

Comment: @Gareth, it's more complicated than that, because e.g. the 2nd least significant column only has 27 possible values if the 3rd least significant column is ''. Otherwise it's restricted to 'A'..'Z'.

Comment: @PeterTaylor True. I know it took a good half hour or so of fiddling to get my version to give the correct result.

Comment: r1c1 notation is allowed?

Comment: That would be too easy :)

Comment: This is a super old challenge, but I'm a bit flummoxed why you've specified a 0-based index, since Excel itself uses a 1-based index.`=ADDRESS(1,1)` returns `$A$1`. See Dr. belisarius' Excel answer.

Comment: @BradC - You know, I don't really remember anymore. :) It could be that I'm just used to 0-based indexing. Or maybe we did use that result as an index in a 0-based array (we used C#). Or maybe that's how it appears internally in the XLSX files. Anyways, converting from 0-based to 1-based is just a `+1`, so it doesn't matter much. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <del>16</del> 14 bytes

```perl6
{("A"..*)[$_]}
```

Works even beyond XFD. Thanks to infinite lists in Perl 6, this doesn't take forever (and a half) to execute.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYPu/WkPJUUlPT0szWiU@tva/NVdafpGCgY6CoY6CkSkQmwGxuY6CKZBvagQUNjO2MFbQtVNQqVCo5lIAguJEkEkaKhWa1ly1/wE)

Answer (score 22):

### Excel Formula:), 36 chars

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,A1,4),"1","")
```

Usage:

[image]

Sorry, couldn't resist ...

Comment: Arghh! I had actually thought of prohibiting this, but forgot to mention it in the post! :D Still, Excel formulas are not a programming language (and yes, Excel VBA is off limits too). :P

Comment: @Vilx- Thanks God someone came up with a shorter solution. I don't want to enter history being the only person who won a golf contest using Excel formulas :)

Comment: I still might accept your answer. >:D

Comment: @Vilx- That would be slightly sadistic on your part :)

Comment: `<laughter type="evil">Muhahahahaha!</laughter>`

Comment: You can drop 2 bytes by replacing `"1"` with `1`

Comment: `=@TEXTSPLIT(ADDRESS(1,A1,2),"$")` would be 32 bytes using ms365 insiders function `TEXTSPLIT()`.

Answer (score 11):

### Perl, 17 characters

```
say[A..XFD]->[<>]
```

The `..` operator does the same thing as the magical auto-increment, but without the need for the temporary variable and loop. Unless `strict subs` is in scope, the barewords `A` and `XFD` are interpreted as strings.

(*This answer was [suggested](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1786) by an anonymous user as an edit to [an existing answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3971/generate-excel-column-name-from-index/3979#3979).  I felt it deserves to be a separate answer, and have made it one.  Since it wouldn't be fair for me to gain rep from it, I've made it Community Wiki.*)

Comment: Since it's the shortest answer so far, I guess it deserves to be marked as "accepted" until a shorter solution is found (probably only available in JonSkeetScript) :P Ironic.

Comment: Since the question is vague on how input and output are done, that actually allows shortening this considerably.  For example, if input is in `$_` and the output is the value of the expression, then `(A..XFD)[$_]` solves the challenge with only **12 chars**.

Comment: Sorry how should this be run?  With perl 5.18 it prints nothing when given as the argument to -E.

Comment: @EdAvis: It's waiting for you to type in a number. Or you could put the number in a file and do `perl -E 'say[A..XFD]->[<>]' < number.txt`. Or, in shells that support it, just give the input on the command line with `perl -E 'say[A..XFD]->[<>]' <<< 123`.

Comment: I think this can be optimized to `say+(A..XFD)[<>]`

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, 48

```
f=(!!)(sequence=<<(tail$iterate(['A'..'Z']:)[]))
```

Less golfed:

```
f n = (concatMap sequence $ tail $ iterate (['A'..'Z'] :) []) !! n
```

#### Explanation

Haskell's [`sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3asequence) combinator takes a list of actions and performs them, returning the result of each action in a list.  For example:

```
sequence [getChar, getChar, getChar]
```

is equivalent to:

```
do
    a <- getChar
    b <- getChar
    c <- getChar
    return [a,b,c]
```

In Haskell, actions are treated like values, and are glued together using the `>>=` (bind) and `return` primitives.  Any type can be an "action" if it implements these operators by having a [Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aMonad) instance.

Incidentally, the list type has a monad instance.  For example:

```
do
    a <- [1,2,3]
    b <- [4,5,6]
    return (a,b)
```

This equals `[(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6)]` .  Notice how the list comprehension is strikingly similar:

```
[(a,b) | a <- [1,2,3], b <- [4,5,6]]
```

Because lists are a type of "action", we can use `sequence` with lists.  The above can be expressed as:

```
sequence [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Thus, `sequence` gives us combinations for free!

Thus, to build the list:

```
["A","B"..."Z","AA","AB"]
```

I just need to build lists to pass to `sequence`

```
[['A'..'Z'],['A'..'Z','A'..'Z'],...]
```

Then use [`concatMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aconcatMap) to both apply `sequence` to the lists, and concatenate the resulting lists.  Coincidentally, `concatMap` is the `=<<` function for lists, so the list monad lets me shave a few characters here, too.

Answer (score 6):

### C, 53 characters

It's like playing golf with a hammer...

```
char b[4],*p=b+3;f(i){i<0||(*--p=i%26+65,f(i/26-1));}
```

Normal version:

```
char b[4];
char *p = b+3;
void f(int i) {
    if (i >= 0) {
        --p;
        *p = i%26 + 65;
        f(i/26-1);
    }
}
```

And the usage is like that:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    f(atoi(argv[1]));
    printf("%s\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, 26 characters

```
$x='A';map$x++,1..<>;say$x
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Ruby, 35 characters

```
e=->n{a=?A;n.times{a.next!};a}
```

Usage:

```
puts e[16383]   # XFD
```

Note: There is also a shorter version (30 characters) using recursion.

```
    e=->n{n<1??A:e[n-1].next}
```

But using this function you might have to increase the stack size for large numbers depending on your ruby interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

## Groovy, 47

```
m={it<0?'':m(((int)it/26)-1)+('A'..'Z')[it%26]}

[0:'A',1:'B',25:'Z',
        26:'AA',
        27:'AB',
        51:'AZ',
        52:'BA',
        16383:'XFD'].collect {k,v-> assert v == m(k);m(k) }
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 45 <s>51</s>

```
f=lambda i:i>=0and f(i/26-1)+chr(65+i%26)or''
```

Comment: you can remove 2 parentheses by pulling `+chr(65+i%26)` inside and testing for `i>=0`, saving you 1 character :)

Comment: You could also shave 4 characters off by using `f=lambda i:` rather than `def f(i):return`

Comment: actually that doesn't work well for numbers 37 and above. I had to update this code a bit: `f = lambda i: i >= 0 and f(math.floor(i / 26 - 1)) + chr(int(round(65 + i % 26))) or ''`

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 30 bytes

```php
for($c=A;$argn--;)$c++;echo$c;
```

Run as pipe with `-nr' or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c14b95165411e7e3da7e79e05f1c08c9dd82f0f8).

Answer (score 3):

### Excel (MS365), 32 bytes.

```
=TEXTBEFORE(ADDRESS(1,A1,4),"1")
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms Sir, gracias .

Answer (score 2):

### Scala, 62 characters

```
def f(i:Int):String=if(i<0)""else f((i/26)-1)+(i%26+65).toChar
```

Usage:

```
println(f(16383))
```

returns:

```
XFD
```

You can try this on [Simply scala](http://www.simplyscala.com/). Copy and paste the function and use `f(some integer)` to see the result.

Comment: You don't need the `""+` on the `else` case.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel VBA, 31 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from cell `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vba
?Replace([Address(1,A1,4)],1,"")
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 57 bytes (recursive)

```java
String f(int n){return n<0?"":f(n/26-1)+(char)(n%26+65);}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##RY/BisJADIbvfYpQEGYYrLXFslhln2BPHtXDWNvduG0qM6kg0mev4zjgJZDk5/uSi77p@eX8P1WtthZ@NNIjArCsGSuYdmyQfqERSAwkH6bmwRDQJv2O43UjaJEV86VUovrTRgqaZYUqVrIcpzJymOtwah0m0G49nqFzBvHG7o9avmQAXFsWqSx90/TG63CbpSVutrmrSkm/C1EMUd8si/wr94Mx@pzuZe/wixVEu7vlukv6gZOrO4FbEqji9YFj5X6UgTJOTw)

**Explanation:**

```java
String f(int n){        // Recursive method with integer parameter and String return-type
  return n<0?           //  If `n` is negative:
    ""                  //   Return an empty String
   :                    //  Else:
    f(n/26-1)           //   Recursive call with `n` integer-divided by 26, minus 1
    +(char)(n%26+65);}  //   And append `n%26+65` as character
```

---

## Java 10, 62 bytes (iterative)

```java
n->{var r="";for(;n>=0;n=n/26-1)r=(char)(n%26+65)+r;return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZZDBasMwDIbvfQoRGNiYZGnCwpjnvsF66XHbwUvTzl2qFFkJjJJnz5zEt10Ekn7@/5MudrDp5fgz1a31Ht6sw/sGwCE3dLJ1A/u5BTgwOTxDLcIGUOowHDeheLbsatgDgoEJ0919sARkkkSfOhIadybXaPCxqNKtJCPqb0tS4ENRqepJKtLUcE8IpMdJz463/qsNjtF46NwRroFKrATvn1auRNx4FvlCAjBnzWTOFLl2r6YMVSm57KLURenSbKvyufx3xRK2imevGHT49dxcs67n7BYQuEXhVPLywYnCLDxERp9x@gM)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                      // Method with integer parameter and String return-type
  var r="";               //  Result-String, starting empty
  for(;n>=0;              //  Loop as long as `n` is not negative
      n=n/26-1)           //    After every iteration: divide `n` by 26, and subtract 1
    r=(char)(n%26+65)+r;  //   Prepend `n%26+65` as character to the result-String
  return r;}              //  Return the result-String
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry but I stole your code : [Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163919/79762). :)

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Hehe, no problem. I actually got mine from the [Scala answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3972/52210). ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 50 bytes

```javascript
f=_=>_<0?'':f(_/26-1)+String.fromCharCode(_%26+65)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbe1i7exsBeXd0qTSNe38hM11BTO7ikKDMvXS@tKD/XOSOxyBmoVCNe1chM28xU839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqGm5n8A)

Seeing that a lot of people started answering this I answered too.

## Note :

This is basically a rip off of @kevinCruijssen's answer in Java shortened thanks to this being JS.

Answer (score 1):

## VBA/VB6/VBScript (non-Excel), 73 bytes

```
Function s(i):While i:i=i-1:s=Chr(i Mod 26+65)&s:i=i\26:Wend:End Function
```

Calling `s(16383)` will return `XFC`.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Can you add an explanation for users unfamiliar with VB?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Not much to add to previous answers, just language bind!

Comment: This appears to fail on all cases where `i>675`  - `s(676)=A@@`(expected `YZ`), `s(677)=A@A` (expected `ZA`)

Comment: @TaylorScott You're right. Working on it...

Comment: @TaylorScott Corrected, +6 bytes... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 71 bytes

```
[range(1;4)as$l|[65+range(26)]|implode/""|combinations($l)]|map(add)[N]
```

Expects input in `N`. e.g.

```
def N:16383;
```

Expanded:

```
[                       # create array with
   range(1;4) as $l     #  for each length 1,2,3
 | [65+range(26)]       #   list of ordinal values A-Z
 | implode/""           #   converted to list of strings ["A", "B", ...]
 | combinations($l)     #   generate combinations of length $l
]
| map(add)[N]           # return specified element as a string
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcnRDoIgGEDhV2HmhS5YicFavoMvwLz4C2o4BBKoG549cnX5nTM/i1R3NF7QEVOGKceM4o73535AOxRViOgFJqlQxAr2oZpuOLUQapMFZ/t/orydsl68cVIdqirf3HLVFqJ2NjS12eYCvgEpWzFOpXyc/61CiE3GEG19ihtWeBOX4oYv)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 147 bytes

I had a similar problem. This is the golf of the solution. Excel columns are [bijective base-26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration#The_bijective_base-26_system).

```
n=>{f=Math.floor;m=Math.max;x=m(0,f((n-24)/676));y=m(0,f(n/26-x*26));return String.fromCharCode(...[x,y,n+1-x*676-y*26].filter(d=>d).map(d=>d+64))}
```

Expanded, except using 1-indices:

```
function getColName(colNum){ // example: 16384 => "XFD"
    let mostSig = Math.max(0, Math.floor((colNum - 26 - 1)/26**2));
    let midSig = Math.max(0, Math.floor((colNum - mostSig*26**2 - 1)/26));
    let leastSig = colNum - mostSig*26**2 - midSig*26;

    return String.fromCharCode(...[mostSig,midSig,leastSig].filter(d=>d).map(d=>d+64));
}
```

Comment: You could add a TIO link. Other than that a great first answer. Also welcome to PPCG.

Comment: Also answering a question asked 7 years ago is not really a great idea.

Comment: Ok , nvm this is wrong on so many levels how did I ever not see this

Comment: I wanted to ask this question but it was a duplicate. I'm not sure what you're getting at @MuhammadSalman

Comment: I will get back to you in a minute, Anyways welcome to PPCG. nice answer. Plz note that when writing an answer you must provide a full program or a function

Comment: Here is an updated and one that is acceptable according to rules : [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY29DsIgGEV3H6T5QKCWKE506ezkaBxI6Z8p0NDG0A59dSRx0fGem5zzUm81136YFmqdbmIro5UlGHlTS8@MCiRIAyey7wCW8gvKQUkuMOYIIbL@fAErWqCci8Q3@d0r5oLcFz/YjrXemapXvkoZYIw9AlnJ9kyNCbQsdZbpozgna6ydnd3YsNF10AK/InT4R0WKxw8 "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 59 bytes

```forth
: f dup 0< if drop else 26 /mod 1- recurse 65 + emit then ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hczRCsIwDAXQ937FZa@yGgdOcfsZaVNX2GzJuu@vqc@CEEi4nNyQpCz9K7RV6wMB/sigGVEvSRm87oxhxHlLHpcewu4QjcYrTuAtFpSF35j0tzRH8AlRe/b8dIw1acdkCpzomIZuNDT4j92JvvSnM7aDtbarHw)

### Explanation

```forth
dup 0<            \ duplicate the top of the stack and check if negative
if drop           \ if negative, drop the top of the stack
else              \ otherwise
   26 /mod        \ divide by 26 and get the quotient and remainder
   1- recurse     \ subtract one from quotient and recurse on result
   65 + emit      \ add 65 to remainder and output ascii char
then              \ exit if statement
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 65 bytes

Recursive answer as are many previous answers.

```r
function(n,u=LETTERS[n%%26+1])"if"(n<=25,u,paste0(g(n%/%26-1),u))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxCoMwEIDhVxEhcEdPak4SO@jo1ql1Kx2KNHLLKWny/Gnm//9i2aeuhKxbkkNBKc/3ZV2Xx/OlxrC/2De2ElrQaWZHmc7PL3172EHNtfbOImXEEo4I0og2G/Rkqa7siUdylhyT9cNtQDyjaKpUKvgD)

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 68 bytes

```powershell
param($n)for(;$n-ge0;$n=($n-$r)/26-1){$s=[char](($r=$n%26)+65)+$s}$s
```

Alternative recursive version, 68 bytes:

```powershell
filter g{if($_-ge0){(($_-($r=$_%26))/26-1|f)+[char]($r+65)}else{''}}
```

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

param($n)for(;$n-ge0;$n=($n-$r)/26-1){$s=[char](($r=$n%26)+65)+$s}$s

}

filter g{if($_-ge0){(($_-($r=$_%26))/26-1|f)+[char]($r+65)}else{''}}


@(
    ,(0 , "A")
    ,(1 , "B")
    ,(25 , "Z")
    ,(26 , "AA")
    ,(27 , "AB")
    ,(51 , "AZ")
    ,(52 , "BA")
    ,(676 , "ZA")
    ,(702 , "AAA")
    ,(16383 , "XFD")
) | % {
    $n, $expected = $_
    $result = &$f $n
    # $result = $n|g      # Alternative
    "$($result-eq$expected): $result"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: A
True: B
True: Z
True: AA
True: AB
True: AZ
True: BA
True: ZA
True: AAA
True: XFD
```

Note: Powershell does not provide a `div` operator.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```ruby
->n{(?A..).take(n+1).last}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuha7dO3yqjXsHfX0NPVKErNTNfK0DTX1chKLS2ohClYVKLhFG5oZWxjHQgQWLIDQAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 30 bytes

```
=@TEXTSPLIT(ADDRESS(1,A1,4),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 48

I really thought that I would be able beat the other Haskell entry, but alas...

```
f(-1)=""
f n=f(div n 26-1)++[toEnum$mod n 26+65]
```

I am certain it is possible to shave a couple of characters off this, but I haven't coded in Haskell for nearly a year, so I am quite rusty.

It's not exactly what you would call elegant.

Comment: Not bad! :) But Ha - after more than 3 years, still no C# solution. :D

Comment: Haha, indeed. But a C# solution is trivial to write using this same method. `string f(int n){return n<0?"":f(n/26-1)+(char)(n%26+65);}` 57 characters, so I would almost feel bad by posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 29 bytes

```
!v:2d*%:"A"+@-2d*,1-:0(?!
$<o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X7HMyihFS9VKyVFJ20EXyNQx1LUy0LBX5FKxyf///79umYKhmbGFMQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 58 bytes

```
procedure f(n);return(n<0&"")|f(n/26-1)||char(65+n%26);end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc5BCoNADAXQfU8hQktCKdWRSQt6GRkjzsJYguJm7m6nu5rs/oOfJIZFjuOjS@BhUy5GEGyV100FpKtuZYkp29PRo8aUwtQrkL/L1RG2LMNfde6jAF6KPLvGlWGECs@5Ntl5C2ThZcDbHd7ZI9S8m2y/774)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `successor`, 27 bytes

```
[ "A"[ successor ] repeat ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owc3LocGefu5WCumpealFiTmZVYklmfl5xQoFRaklJZUFRZl5JQrFqYWlqXnJqcUKxaXJQKo4v0jBmourmksBCAwUwEBRQddOwREsYogk4gQWMTJFiERBRMyQdEG0GZkjCUH0mRoiCUE0mhohGQ61z0zH2MIYIhTh5sJVu7S0JE3XYne0gpKjUjSSm2MVilILUhNLFGIhKlblJhYoFJckJmfrQQQWLIDQAA)

Yup, Factor has a vocab for this.

Comment: Still not as crazy as mathematica

Answer (score 0):

## C (GCC), 39 bytes

```c
f(i){i>25&&f(i/26-1);putchar(65+i%26);}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##jc7BCsIwDAbge58iDDZau2E32A5WfRH1UCqdOThHmV5Gn722ojiQDXPJT/IFootWa@8NRTbivqqzLMR11RQlk/190BdlaVNzTKuGSeexG@CqsKMxKNvqHCKBVciPw4mRkcC7zM3CiyHsQMjQtlCKEDhHBl/3qd4GbGiSnjeQ5IBM/pD4pZw9PHbJZOsIWQaGhm/EZLDE/nbz0Pkn)

Explanation:

```c
f(i)
{
    // If i cannot be represented as a single letter
    i>25 &&
        // Print the next letter
        f(i/26-1);
    
    // Print the current letter
    putchar(65+i%26);
}
```

I thought using 0-based indexing was a little strange, so here's 1-based indexing in the same number of bytes:

```c
f(i){i-->26&&f(i/26);putchar(65+i%26);}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##jc69CsIwEADgPU9xFFoS02AtmMGoL6IOIZJ6g7GE6lL67DERxYK0eMv9fQdnRGNMCJYi61GIfS2LIjbLWjLV3jtz0Z7KNcc8DYaAroOrRkdToX1jSkgEFrF@HE6M9ATeYW8eXgxhBysV0zbmqlLAOTL4wk@0PmpLs/y8gawEZOqHpDfV5OHRZaPtQMg8sDR@U40Gc@xvNw0HEp4)