# Spreadsheet Columns

Tags: code-golf, sequence, arithmetic, alphabet

## Spreadsheet Columns

In most spreadsheet programs, columns go `A`, `B`, `C`, ... `X`, `Y`, `Z`. After this comes `AA`, `AB`, `AC` ... `AX`, `AY`, `AZ`, `BA` and so on.

Your task is to convert one of these strings in to a column *number*. You must support inputs up to the maximum length of your language, to a minimum of 3.

### Test Cases:

```
A   => 1
B   => 2
Z   => 26
AA  => 27
AC  => 29
AZ  => 52
BA  => 53
FC  => 159
ID  => 238
AAA => 703
```

Standard loopholes are forbidden.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3971/58974), borderline dupe.

Comment: Also a subset of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/139221/58974), which would probably be a better dupe target.

Comment: @Shaggy you were one step away from the exact dupe :-)

Comment: @Giuseppe, A-ha! That was the challenge I set out to find but it didn't show up when searching for "spreadsheet" or "Excel".

Comment: @Shaggy No! I've been duped!

Comment: @Giuseppe Above, but SE only allows one mention.

Comment: Back to the drawing board, I guess.

Comment: @gadzooks02 yes, alas, a good challenge but one already done. Feel free to post in [The Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback if you want any; this can sometimes help catch dupes, although sometimes challenges just languish there for way too long. In that case, drawing additional attention to it [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) can help as well.

Comment: @Giuseppe Yeah. I already have another idea :)

Comment: Um, you *did* put this in the Sandbox, where [I told you it was a dupe](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/18134#comment65279_18134). What's the point of ignoring feedback?

Comment: @JoKing Ah yes, I hadn't noticed.