# Given a string, calculate the number of the column it corresponds to

Tags: code-golf, math

In Excel, the columns range from `A-Z, AA,AB,AZ,BA,..,BZ` and so on. They actually each stand for numbers, but rather are encoded as alphabet strings.

In this challenge, you will be given a string of alphabets, and you must calculate the column it corresponds to.

Some tests:

> 'A' returns 1 (meaning that it is the first column)
>
> 'B' returns 2
>
> 'Z' returns 26
>
> 'AA' returns 27
>
> 'AB' returns 28
>
> 'AZ' returns 52
>
> 'ZZ' returns 702
>
> 'AAA' returns 703

You can assume that capital letters will be given only.

Shortest bytes win.

Good luck!

Comment: So... base 26 with the alphabet?

Comment: It isn't quite base 26 because there's no zero.

Comment: @J.Doe Ah, I guess you're right. I didn't notice since my solution automatically treated `Z` as 10 anyway

Comment: [Reverse challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3971/generate-excel-column-name-from-index?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @JoKing [Bijective base](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54105/all-your-bijective-base-are-belong-to-us?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I wonder if someone will come up with a solution in Excel.

Comment: Can we take input as an array/list of characters?

Comment: @Titus I don't have Excel or know it... but isn't there a `COLUMN` function that would do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 17 bytes

```perl6
{:26[.ords X-64]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv9rKyCxaL78opVghQtfMJLb2f3FipUKahpKjkqY1F5TthMSOQmI7IityRFbliKwsClUPWNN/AA)

Anonymous code block that subtracts 64 from each byte value and converts from base 26 with `Z` overflowing to the next column.

Answer (score 8):

## Google Sheets, 21 bytes

(formula evaluates to the result, takes input from cell A1)

```
=column(indirect(A1&2
```

Comment: Just about to post a slightly less golfed version of this.

Comment: I also have a solution in Google Sheets that doesn't rely on builtin COLUMN, check it out. (besides, I feel bad that the solution I put more effort on gets less attention... it's a typical problem with voting anyway, especially when the challenge is on HNQ.)

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>48</s> 43 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to @Giuseppe, using the same logic, but as a program that eliminates the `nchar` call.

```r
for(i in utf8ToInt(scan(,"")))F=F*26+i-64;F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPobQkzSIk3zOvRKM4OTFPQ0dJSVNT083WTcvITDtT18zE2u2/o6PjfwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 39 bytes

```java
s->s.chars().reduce(0,(a,b)->a*26+b%32)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY89a8MwEIZ3/4rDYJBSW5SUdkgagzoUOnRKp5QO8lcq15aMdA6E4t/uSrLJ0kEn7rn3HqRWXETWVj@z7AdtEFrXsxFlxzb76B9rRlWi1MoPo7IT1sK7kAp@I4BhLDpZgkWB7rpoWUHvZuSIRqrz5xcIc7Y0RAE@9JvC19X2vERyaOAw2yy3rPwWxhLKTF2NZU3uUyLSgma52Gyf7orkYUvnffDc5FhbtHBY9QAxj1OIX3w5@cJDzwPggZxWzuOwMi3CRhtYnxycu8VMb@Lj1WLdMz0iG1wKGxInj3YHSZUoJ/TpFBomhqG7cut@STyidNFPkT/T/Ac)

Comment: Which java platform supports this ?

Comment: @SyedHamzaHassan Java 8 or more.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>52</s> 45 bytes

```python
t=0
for c in input():t=26*t+ord(c)%64
print t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxCsJADIbn5imyyLW6SJEOhQ5XqKuLi930Gmmp9I6Qon3686KQ/ycfH0nYZPRLGZ0fCBs0xkRpjvD0jA6nJU1YJS9qacpqLwfPQ@6KXXWCwNMiKDFdALzH6UV45ZVqyIS31Bl9yOX6toC0OwqC3eXcMXtW/WC6z9FYA6ZN6VOsglWyiq1if9P6259O/gs)

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>41</s> 38 bytes

-3 thanks to Jo King.

```php
for($c=A;$c!=$argn;$i++)$c++;echo$i+1;
```

run as pipe with `-nr`

unary output, 34 bytes:

```php
1<?for($c=A;$c!=$argn;$c++)echo 1;
```

requires PHP 7.1. save to file, run as pipe with `-nF`.

Comment: @Rogem check https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/running-php-with-r-instead-of-code-tags

Comment: @Titus Alright then

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
Çžx-₂β
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cPvRfRW6j5qazm36/z8qCgA)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use `žx` instead of just `64`?

Comment: I don't know, it looked nicer I guess?

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>38</s> <s>34</s> 31 bytes

```hs
foldl(\o->(o*26-64+).fromEnum)0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPy0/JyVHIyZf104jX8vITNfMRFtTL60oP9c1rzRX0@B/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmoKSo6PS/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ØAiⱮḅ26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDMfMRxvXPdzRamT2//9/R0dHAA)

Answer (score 2):

## APL(NARS), 11 chars, 22 bytes

```
{+/26⊥⎕A⍳⍵}
```

test

```
  f←{+/26⊥⎕A⍳⍵} 
  f¨'A' 'AA' 'AAA'
1 27 703 
  f¨'AB' 'ZZ' 'Z'
28 702 26
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 11 bytes

```
26#.64|3&u:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WuoKNQa6VgoADE/43MlPXMTGqM1Uqt/mtypSmoO6qDyBAwGQUmHSFUFJTn6Kj@HwA)

#### How it works

```
26#.64|3&u:  Monadic verb. Input: a string.
       3&u:  Convert each character to Unicode codepoint
    64|      Modulo 64; maps A -> 1, ... Z -> 26
26#.         Interpret as base-26 digits and convert to single integer
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 48 bytes

```javascript
f=([h,...t],p=0)=>h?f(t,p*26+parseInt(h,36)-9):p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcjRCsIgFIDhx/Gc5SQKBhUu3F2vsLELWZqLpYcpsbe3SRf/xfe/9VfHaZ0p1T48Tc5WwuC4ECKNnOQRZevuFhKn6tQcSK/RPHwCx88N1he8Ur5NwcewGLGEFwxMMc66vX5PFagiVdj/n2Kj@GiCTbYWNkTMPw)

Comment: `.map()` is [1 byte shorter](https://tio.run/##Zc3BDoIgHIDxe0/BTShF04V1wE1vvYKtAyNsNYP/xHXq3WnZog3Ov@377uIprJxuMGfaXJQbuLO8OVFK7Zk@BGDJG@CwLtkGxGTVUc9YphUj2SEFXpAXOGm0NaOio7niASdtQghCKM/RdhVQ56kMqf8TC639Jj9WR9Z520fW/2wX/7zVRRkPl@OClXsD). Using `Buffer()` [saves another byte](https://tio.run/##Zc3BDoIgAIDhe0/BTahEosIuuMlj6DwwElczYVKdendatmiD87f9/1U@pVPzxd7zyZx7r7l3vGoxxq7DN2mh4pXldk3ZRjy07meoUEu6nB22lhP0sl6ZyZmxx6MZoIZZnSEEACgKsFtFJALRmJo/sdjqb/JjZWIi2Cmx5mfH9BesJDQdLscF9/4N).

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##Zc27DsIgGEDh3adgK2hvolIXmpTH6EYQTE0tf0p18t0x1ogJzF9yzk0@pVPzAEsx2Yv2hnvHW/EwRs/YkfIuASveAoctZTtVsGMOvCYv8MpOzo66HO0VG5x1GSEIoapC@01EIhCNqf8Ti637Jj/WJCaCnRPrf3ZKf8GamqbD9bjiwb8B), expanding on @Arnauld's suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 92 bytes

```java
static int m(String v){int x=0;for(int i=0;i<v.length();i++)x=x*26+v.charAt(i)-64;return x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZCxboMwEIbn@ilOTHZRUBpVWRwGZ@yajaqDQyi5FAyyjUUV8ezEBKdTgyXLd7rP@n7dRTq5upx@RsgraQx8@F60bYW5tNiotzVcCQGA6ULbHf0AjPWzHFyDJ6glKnqwGlX5@QVSl4b5HxDOXLwcfo0t6qTpbNJ60laKRiKN4to/EWOc/EvsZ2L/nMhmIntOiIdmwSOCSCyYRFCJBVf2iLOY5y/QPRGQgQAZw0Y9BHXYJjh2nfo@XfPvRtOpRl/jziVVoUp7poxjHLM@7V8329gl@VlqYSmy1fad68J2WkHPh3EYbw)

**Output**

> A=1
>
> B=2
>
> Z=26
>
> AA=27
>
> AB=28
>
> AZ=52
>
> ZZ=702
>
> AAA=703

Comment: I'm not an expert at golfing Java, but you can golf this down considerably by returning instead of printing, simplifying the for loops, removing whitespace and getting rid of the `p` and `n` variables. [92 bytes!](https://tio.run/##hZAxj8IwDIXny6@wmJKrqDh0YgkMYWRl43RDKKUY2rRK3KgI9bf3Uuh6wZKl9/TZz5Kv2uv59XQbICu1c7ALXjVNiZkmrM3XAh6MAcDY0LTHAMBRYBn4Gk9QaTR8TxZN8fML2hZOhA2Y6iU@9ndHeZXWLaVNmKTS8IrP1EwIyf6B2xg8xKCK5qposIomH97cfR4G1jNgw/SjQKGa/gNePEbfbRbyXFs@agwa1z4tc1PQhQuJSSK6Tfe5XCU@zS7aKuIo5qtvaXNqrYFO9kM//AE "Java (JDK) – Try It Online").

Comment: Wonderful.......

Comment: You can remove `static` to gain 7 bytes. You could also make this function a lambda to spare more bytes. I also think that the recursive version might save bytes. In any case, here's [my 39 bytes solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174395/16236).

Comment: That's Wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 20 bytes

```
[:(#.~26$~#)32|a.i.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8D/aSkNZr87ITKVOWdPYqCZRL1Mv9r8ml5KegnqarZ66go5CrZVCWjEXV2pyRr5CmoK6ozqc6YRgRiGYjkgqHJGUOCKpiUJR76j@HwA)

### Explanation:

```
 [:(#.~26$~#)32|a.i.] 
                  i.    - indices 
                    ]   - of the characters of the input
                a.      - in the alphabet
             32|        - mod 32
 [:(        )           - apply the following code to the above
         $~             - create a list of (left and right arguments exchanged) 
       26               - the number 26
           #            - repeated the length of the input times
    #.~                 - to base (26)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 bytes

```apl
⎕A∘⍳⊥⍨26⍴⍨≢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhEd9Ux0fdcx41Lv5UdfSR70rjMwe9W4B0o86FwEVKKg7qnMBSScwGQUmHSFCjhAxR4hgFEzOUR0A)

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 100 bytes

(formula evaluates to the result, takes input from cell A1)

```
=sum(arrayformula(
  (
    code(
      mid(A1,row(indirect("1:"&len(A1))),1)
    )-64
  )*26^row(indirect("1:"&len(A1)))/26
```

All spaces are added for clarity only.

*Note*.

- I don't know if it's possible to remove the duplication of `row(indirect("1:"&len(A1))`.
- Although Google Sheets has a `decimal` function, the transliteration would takes a lot of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 12 bytes

Index origin 1.

```
26⊥¯65+⎕av⍳⎕
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/4bmT3qWnpovZmpNlAisexR72Yg/R8o9T@NS93R0VEdAA)

Explanation:

```
⎕av⍳⎕ Prompts for input and gets Ascii integer value for each character

¯65+ subtracts 65 to give integers 1-26 for A-Z

26⊥ converts resulting vector from base 26 to single integer
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
Ｉ↨²⁶ＥＳ⊕⌕αι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwymxOFXDyExHwTexQMMzr6C0JLgEKJuuoamj4JmXXJSam5pXkpqi4ZaZl6KRqKOQqQkG1v//Ozr91y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
     Ｓ      Input string
    Ｅ       Map over characters
         ι  Current character
        α   Uppercase alphabet
       ⌕    Find index
      ⊕     Increment
  ²⁶        Literal 26
 ↨          Base conversion
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>46</s>, 43 bytes

```c
a;f(int*s){for(a=0;*s;)a=*s++%64+a*26;s=a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc1Na8JAEAbgs/6KYUTYTRRsqrG4LGUFC6JQ8OMiXpZ0VwIaJSO0EPLXu66hWoyXObzPzLxJd5ckzmlhWZqdA@KFPeZMy54ISHAtAwrDdtwPdRDFgqQWpWt9GZtmBtRyOVmsmPk5cWCFv4bcEEioEnHKfWIZKiKTn6FNI8CWF9xm2LluvuPnDEf4oabz9WKCXJS8edBpxnjRbPz9tmyOCjkASOnHCxcPNP6nqEabO0VxjVT1saJhncZ3eqvT5kaDp64bDXvRU9e1rKJXT6X7Texe78h1vy8)

### Degolf

```c
a; f(int*s)
{  for(a=0;*s;) // Loop through s, which is a null-terminated string.
       a=*s++%64 + a*26; // Multiply accumulated value by 26, and add current char modulo 64 to it.
   s=a;} // Return the accumulated value.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Japt `-h`, 10 bytes

```
åÈ*26+InYc
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=5cgqMjYrSW5ZYw==&input=IkFBQSIKLWg=)

Or without a flag. The first byte can be removed if we can take input as a character array.

```
¬®c aIÃì26
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=rK5jIGFJw+wyNg==&input=IkFBQSI=)

---

### Explanation

```
åÈ             :Cumulatively reduce by passing each character at Y through a function, with an initial total of 0
  *26          :  Multiply current total by 26
     -I        :  Subtract 64
       n       :   Subtracted from
        Yc     :    The codepoint of Y
               :Implicitly output the last element of the resulting array
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
0w"26*@+64-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/36BcychMy0HbzET3/391R0dHdQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 36 bytes

```
{it.fold(0){o,n->o*26+n.toInt()-64}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxCsIwFEV3v@KR6UXbIiIdihbi5uTg1i0gKcH0paRPQUK@PbbVOxy4h8t9enaW8ls7MA3eOVjqZdleieEMOVqujHcP3MvoCypbvz3UO6rYzwOUZX1MKZsXwaAtoQ791IAKQX9Ov6dWxg3McXbim0GhRAHisqBboNauVqFW0/29ErIa9AhxnG/YERq0LGXapPwF)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 18 bytes

```ruby
->s{[*?A..s].size}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664OlrL3lFPrzhWrzizKrX2f4FCWrSSo1IsF4QBZP0HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## x86 machine code, 19 bytes

```
00000000: 31c0 8b19 83e3 3f41 b21a f7e2 01d8 3831  1.....?A......81
00000010: 75f0 c3                                  u..
```

Assembly:

```
section .text
	global func
func:				;this function uses fastcall conventions
	xor eax, eax		;reset eax to 0
	loop:
		;ebx=*ecx%64
		mov ebx, [ecx]	;ecx is 1st arg to this func (in fastcall conventions)
		and ebx, 63	;because 64 is a pwr of 2,n%64=n&(64-1)

		;ecx++		get next char in str by incrementing ptr
		inc ecx
		
		;eax=eax*26
		mov dl, 26	;using an 8bit reg is less bytes
		mul edx
		
		;eax+=ebx //(eax=(*ecx%64)+(eax*26))
		add eax, ebx

		;if(*ecx!='\0')goto loop
		cmp byte [ecx], dh ;dh==0
		jne loop
	ret			;return value is in eax
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVRRb5swEH6GX3GL2gJJSNI0yrZQKrVap73tvSWKjDGEjtjINilVmt@enR22JVORML677@6@O59JiVofKNFwe/v48zvcwVhv6jEZEbWBCLj5hDmr8pvpqSUUR4mKjI0EAhldC/BYq5nksFoRrWWZNpqtVr6fE6UpqaoggJJryBtOfbomsh9EG1JyP9hZSTOln5fxrnffG/bu7fKAy9OTFVGe7KNcSN/EKONJZPHlMioHg6CWqM393qVawGWW8N6wsw5ttk4Igmjv/SlR6SYd0ShxE7eg9LwirPcUdFZryEVYlwzCzc3Ueov0JWs2NYTfznCYJmNbjJAxKc@B6gz4DpqxUzBqCskQ9wje8yT8utzN9uChljYawhQ@h7Pph15aQpiBl3Dvn2AdLdSkbNtspFsN769YMUULef0F3s62Dy6ux9O9gR@7Cb2E9/v9hzfNgIqG6wVKCb9U2F648M3MhMEHZdpRCFnn/oO1pmjcLXpwdzWNADlAiOTq/ygZgwEk7tlBHBSjuhQcRhrHy3WKSqSkslPkmmXh4BPpdamszkIbxVDqxg7J8y3jxqBcpxUSGGmHZkE/yRTTZg9awMR1KiHqhYsGlrZxn9H2cj5DcSO2gJohPKNqiVbaAia8VhqILIzvXwKAA/ph7gDjEJ4d48xvnChllCBTmM9MLAL1qwSRw3TIMWnMr/z5LLwOXMuGtoOB4xTIlWMXwFwYvEyg8JTTN9xRyTYmDy@g1hJdUIWXssWd9SdtjG9/Ou@KyaohTOdO1CjjQjh8SUsNkhWGSsWUwrB4awy6qYBlJ4EGMVYA47Fvgvpdj4KBf4wf2DKzrGty2lr@ZW6Bn2IvmXhBIbBhptNoonghTKpjZ4eQrSHK1nGMZ@G8cNbBJNOOPS3d4P9lS6qGGaLYAUxzwB/X4Tc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 29 bytes

```
{it.fold(0){a,v->v-'@'+a*26}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7NCoJAFEb3PsWHG@dWRrRoIWnNMmjXE1zyh6HxGtMohPjsk2Xf5mwOh@/ReWskDGxx72zfSgZ1885IQ0gLXMQjD6Px27qzpdrRyJshLYY0OSdrXu0P0xTqXtCyEcWueWXQzvH7uDQKwhhh3r@PHMpVXF6NVIpwyhDH9BOes@7VcuELomgKWusP)

### Explained

```
val column: (String) -> Int = {  // String in, Int out
    it.fold(0) { a, v ->  // acc, value
        v - '@'  // distance of char from @ (A=1 etc.)
                + a * 26
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 22 bytes

```
>jvi'@-\26l
^~>O@ ~+*<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/98uqyxT3UE3xsgshyuuzs7fQaFOW8vmf1ppnkJuYmaeRmJRerGVgmNRUWKlTXBJUWZeup2mQjWXAhCUJeYoJOfnKNgqaBQBzfLJzEvV0FSwt1JQUtIEKygAKi/RACopzc0DUZqaXLX/HR0dAQ)

Answer (score 1):

### [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), 84 bytes

```
1 INPUT S$:L=LEN(S$):FOR I=1 TO L:V=ASC(MID$(S$,I,1))-64:T=T+26^(L-I)*V:NEXT:PRINT T
```

Output:

```
? AZ
 52

? ZZ
 702

? AAA
 703
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-nl`, 39 bytes

```ruby
p$_.chars.reduce(0){|x,y|26*x+y.ord-64}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AlXi85I7GoWK8oNaU0OVXDQLO6pkKnssbITKtCu1IvvyhF18yk9v9/Ry4nriguR0cuRycuxyiuKBDb8V9@QUlmfl7xf928HAA)