# Letters associated with prime numbers

Tags: code-golf, primes

If we assign each letter a respective integer, starting from 1, then a is 1, b is 2, c is 3, and so on. After z, the letters loop back around, but with a in front (aa, ab, ac). It then goes to ba, bb, bc... After this is completed, as you may have figured, another letter is added (aaa, aab, aac).  "Prime letters" would be letters that are associated with a prime number. b would be the first prime letter, followed by c, e, g, et cetera.

## The Challenge

Given an input *n*, find the nth "prime letter."

**Examples**

Input:

```
1
```

Output:

```
b
```

Input:

```
4
```

Output:

```
g
```

Input:

```
123
```

Output:

```
za
```

## Scoring Criteria

This is code golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Basically, yes.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a nice first question, but given the task, I believe it is a duplicate (although I can't find it just now). I'd recommend that for your next challenge you post it in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/) first to receive feedback.

Comment: Perhaps include test cases beyond Z?

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/174336/given-a-string-calculate-the-number-of-the-column-it-corresponds-to); this is the inverse (letters->numbers). I think the numbers->letters exists somewhere (even if it's just in a bijective base-n question), and prime-related challenges have been [done to death](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14580/67312). Not saying this is a bad challenge, just that it's a composite of existing ones.

Comment: Suggested test cases of big numbers so you can verify the letter wrapping works correctly.

Comment: Add the test case `123` -> `za`. Several current answers get it wrong.

Comment: How large can *n* be?

Comment: [Also related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3971/generate-excel-column-name-from-index)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),<s>262</s> <s>236</s> <s>209</s> <s>196</s> <s>179</s> <s>114</s> <s>93</s> <s>92</s>  97 bytes

```python
def f(n):
 m=k=1;s=''
 while n:m*=k*k;k+=1;n-=m%k
 while k:s=chr(~-k%26+97)+s;k=~-k//26
 return s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NclLCsMgEADQvaeYTYhGQj6FlCpzmlYxTJwGNYRuenWbTZePt39KePOt1pfz4CUrIyAi4WQztq2AM6ybAzaxQ@rIkr6Ge4wN/Y9MxmdI8ttTMy/6cVc6W8KLwzAvApIrR2LIdU8rF@nlNCpVfw)

Fixed a bug mentioned by @benrg about getting a wrong output for the input 123.

Thanks to:
- @AdmBorkBork for help me getting started and save a few bytes
- @Sriotchilism O'Zaic for saving me 6 bytes
- @mypetlion for saving me 65 bytes and bringing me under 150 bytes :)
- @dingledooper for saving me 21 bytes and bringing me under 100 bytes :D
- @Jitse for saving 1 byte

---

**98 bytes**

```python
f=lambda n,i=1,p=1:n and-~f(n-p%i,i+1,p*i*i)
g=lambda n,s='':n and g(~-n//26,chr(~-n%26+97)+s)or s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIU8n09ZQp8DW0CpPITEvRbcuTSNPt0A1UydTGyislamVqcmVjlBcbKuuDlGpkK5Rp5unr29kppOcUQRiqxqZaVuaa2oXa@YXKRT/LyjKzCvRSNdI0zA00NTU/A8A)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf SE! I'm not a Python guy, but I know you can save a bunch of bytes by converting your indents to tabs instead of multiple spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Also, make sure to check out the [Python tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54/42963) thread.

Comment: You might want to give your answer a comb over for extra spaces, I can see 5 spaces right now that are not neccessary.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: It's not required but [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BCsIwEETv/YpFKCS02jZKxMb1R0IPIqnd0G5LrIhfH6uot2HmDTPTc@5G3sbokXgWxNN9FlIaxtIMaJvk0VHvwNecYWX8Gi1BOwYgIIZw5qsTVc6SWuCUEMsG0Va/Fp@UrocMLReF0jmnSjcfUumj2oPrbw6UNkuKSidTeD9YrTZ@JBb20gVx0BnJ/9zQLOprs5Qyxt0L "Python 3 – Try It Online") is a cool site that counts bytes, runs code, and can generate a CG&CC post

Comment: You seem to have a small bug somewhere. I tried a large number: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BCsIwEETv/YogFBJabbtKxMb1R0IPIqnd0G5LrIhfH6uot2HmDTPTc@5G3sbokXiWxNN9lkoZxtIMaJvk0VHvhK85w8r4NVoS7RgECWIRznx1sspZUSs4JcSyQbTVr8Un0PWQoeWiAJ1zCrr5kKCPsBeuvzkB2iwpgk6m8H6wWm38SCztpQvyoDNS/7mhWdTXZqVUjDvQLw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Veskah Thanks for the hint

Comment: 114 bytes with the same approach [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc1BCsIwEEbhfU@RjTRDIzUVA22dw4hUM8H8DTFFPH1UcP8@XnoXv@JYazAwkQVFC9JWNJE5mLZtXl4eiwoTOrZz2PNzixo7OVt1W7MSJVD5gvuirQERs/0LTJGvPn/bwXWjoy7O6HseXJPy7xKpVnv6AA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @mypetlion thank you, may i take your improvement :)

Comment: @Delta Sure. Any improvements posted in the comments are free for you to use. If somebody doesn't want you to use it, they will post it as their own answer.

Comment: 93 bytes by using a better prime algorithm: [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##LcxLCoAgEADQfadoI/kh@oGQMqeJQJmcJI3o9FbQ@sGLd3Y7TaUQeMrcUzwzF8IGQBhsgqapLue3tSYTJKBEi@oFaiEw/AlNgsUdHNmo1ayFSha7DkZdxeNLkyhl6B8)

Comment: @dingledooper Thnak you for the improvement

Comment: -1 byte by using a function instead: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NclLCsMgEADQvaeYTYhGQj4FocqcplEME6dBLaWnN9n0bd/5q/HNj9Y2HyBIVlZAQsLFFex7Ad@4Hx7YpgFpIEf6Hh4xdfQ/sgVfMUvqVqOfRuniaJpwNQKyr5/MUNqZd64yyGVWql0 "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Jitse Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ÆNḃ26ịØa
```

A monadic Link which accepts a non-negative integer that yields a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm9/DHc1GZg93dx@ekfj//39DI2MA)**

#### How?

```
ÆNḃ26ịØa - Link: integer, n
ÆN       - nth prime
   26    - literal 26
  ḃ      - bijective base
      Øa - literal list of characters = ['a', 'b', ..., 'z']
     ị   - index into
```

Comment: For input `123` the output should be `za` but this code currently prints `AZA`.

Comment: Ah it's bijective base decompression, I guess it has to be `ÆNḃ26ịØA` then :(

Comment: ...and that'll be exactly the same as the other Jelly entry becomes.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 83 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,k=0)=>n?f(n-(g=d=>~k%d--?g(d):!d)(++k),k):k<0?'':f(n,k/26-1)+Buffer([k%26+65])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBDoIwEEDRq4wLwkxKtSWxC6SQeA3jglBKsGRqirr06hV3f/PfY/gM25iW50tydFPO3iJXwSqyHfceWeJsne2@oXBS9jM6ag6OUIhAVaAmtKovy8b/p1NtpCZxfXs/JbyFojbCnO@UfUzIYEFfgKEFrdQeQhCMkbe4Tsc1zjsAu0KUfw)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                // f is a recursive function taking:
  n,                 //   n = input
  k = 0              //   k = counter
) =>                 //
  n ?                // if n is not equal to 0:
                     //   == 1st pass: find the requested prime ==
    f(               //   do a recursive call:
      n - (          //     pass the updated value of n
        g = d =>     //     g is a recursive function which takes d = k
                     //     and tests the primality of k + 1:
          ~k % d-- ? //       if d is not a divisor of (k + 1):
                     //       (decrement d afterwards)
            g(d)     //         do recursive calls until it is
          :          //       else:
            !d       //         return true if d = 0
      )(++k),        //     increment k and invoke g
                     //     so we decrement n if k is prime
      k              //     pass k
    )                //   end of recursive call
  :                  // else:
                     //   == 2nd pass: convert the prime to a string ==
    k < 0 ?          //   if k is negative:
      ''             //     return an empty string and stop
    :                //   else:
      f(             //     do a recursive call:
        n,           //       pass n (which is now 0)
        k / 26 - 1   //       pass k / 26 - 1
      ) +            //     end of recursive call
      Buffer([       //     append the letter corresponding to
        k % 26 + 65  //     k mod 26
      ])             //
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 53 bytes

```
Flatten[Tuples[Alphabet[],#]&/@Range@4,1][[Prime@#]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773y0nsaQkNS86pLQgJ7U42jGnICMxKbUkOlZHOVZN3yEoMS891cFExzA2OjqgKDM31UE5NlbtP5CZV6LgkB5tGMsFZ5sgsQ2NjJF5BgYGsf//AwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-rprime`, <s>48</s> <s>47</s> <s>46</s> 43 bytes

-5 bytes from GB.

```ruby
->n{(?A..?Z*n).take(Prime.take(n)[-1])[-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsPeUU/PPkorT1OvJDE7VSOgKDM3FcLM04zWNYwFE7X/NQz19IwMNPVSE5MzFFLyFWoyaxQKSkuKFZRUjVIUVI2KlVSjM3UU0qIzY2OtFVLzUv7/yy8oyczPK/6vW1QAMhQA)

Comment: Use take instead of first for -1 byte.

Comment: And: get nth element of [?a..?a*n] instead of iterating, save 10 bytes.

Comment: @GB the second suggestion unfortunately doesn't work on inputs greater than 5 (both on TIO and my machine). Instead, it runs for a few mintues before it gives `IndexError (index 268435456 too big)` and then the memory overload from constructing the list seems to cause irb segfault as well. I'll use the first suggestion, though!

Comment: You don't need r, actually, you could just use [-1]

Comment: @GB you are right and I'm amazed that I didn't actually connect the dots.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 69 bytes

```php
for($n=1,$a=a;$argn||!print$a;$m||--$argn,$a++)for($m=$n++;$n%$m--;);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYoxCoAwDADfIkSwxAyCWyxu/qOL2qFpqI55u7V0Objj9Na67dp45jKB@GWG4ANDKJeYDVqivNA8mRH12gZE1/fkQRAZZIRExI5rXb@sb8zyVDp@)

Comment: The guy who decided that `$s="z";echo++$s;` should give `"aa"` is either a genius or insane.

Comment: @Arnauld I have seen this in other languages too, but PHP contains about 2 decades of mysteries in it. See this: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLSyVRwVZBPSrKVN2aiystv0hBQyUTKGJgrQCkbRSMwAxtbU2Fai4FIEhNzshX0NYG6tJTUIrJU7Lmqv3/HwA "PHP – Try It Online") and this: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLSyVRwVZBPSrKMkLdmosrLb9IQUMlEyhkYK0ApG0UTEG0tramQjWXAhCkJmfkK2hrA3XpKSjF5ClZc9X@/w8A "PHP – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>170</s> <s>163</s> <s>158</s> <s>157</s> 155 bytes

```java
String p(int n){int c=0,i,v=1;String s="";while(c<n){v++;for(i=2;i<=v;i++)if(v%i<1)break;if(i==v)c++;}while(v>0){s=(char)(~-v%26+97)+s;v=~-v/26;}return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BbsIwEER/xUJC2pUhhKgCVY77B5w4Vj0YY2AhOJHtLKqi9NdTt3Aazcyb1V4Nm@X1eJu6/tCQFbYxMYqdIT@IVxSTSVm4paO45wL2KZA/f36ZcI447L9jcvei7VPR5Tw1Hrx7/J8ALDp4K0tENU7PleggM8Lj8CdWlwtasF6rVxv1bKYeF2oc2DpDLKU6tQFIV4pqzYqkRDoBz6le4yE4c1PZktaMNrPjc8sfJQ5Rg72YgPCz5Hm1ke9blFGxznZVbdQYXOqDFzH/Nk6/)

Thanks to @Delta for saving me 14 bytes in total

Comment: hey you can save some bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5NbsIwEIWvYiEheWRIQ1SBKjO9QVcsqy6MCTAQnMh2BlVRevV0Wlg9fe9nNBfHbnk5XKeu3zfklW9cSurDURjU00rZZRFu6aBuEuhdjhROn18unhIMu@@U61vR9rnoxM9N0KG@/5/QUHT6FcCO02OjOi0NFWD4E4/lgnC1YFzZZ55wNrP3MzW19lupsTH22EZNWFnaIlsyBuioeU6IJexj7a5WWIjBS3l8jPm9hCGh9mcXQf8seV6tzdsGTLKMgi/V2o6xzn0MKsl74/QL "Java (JDK) – Try It Online").

Comment: You can also look her to improve your anwser [Code Golf in java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java)

Comment: [130 bytes](https://tio.run/##RZDBTsMwDIbvewpr0qZEaUtXoSHIPJ6AXTgiDiHLwKNLpySNhqby6iVdKyHFh9/Ob/2fjyqq/Lj/7nWtvIcXRfY6AyAbjDsobWA3SIDX4Mh@gmZpAhcuU7NLlZ4PKpCGHVhA6G2@vQ5fNJYZZRFXcnJ6nM/loXFM6o2VWiAhxufVU8mHZhQiI6wkbTAul3FB21KSEHx0xKQi/ubxrlpzj0x/KcdZ0otqLR4fuPDSmdA6C152vZylVOf2o06ppnCxoT2cEhsb07y9g@IjWDA@sPuynJD@gW6e23REnu7w44M5FU0binPaFGrLbKHZhU/@rv8D "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
<Ø[₂‰˜0KZ27‹#}<Asè
```

Isn't there a convenient builtin to do this shorter?.. I have the feeling I should be able to use one of the base-conversion builtins here, but it isn't really working out.. Can without a doubt be golfed substantially, though..

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//zzDmFvigoLigLDLnDBLWjI34oC5I308QXPDqP//MTIz) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##AT8AwP9vc2FiaWX/dnk/IiAtPiAiP3n/PMOYW@KCguKAsMucMEtaMjfigLkjfTxBc8Oo/yz/WzEsNCwxMjMsMTAwMF0).

**Explanation:**

```python
<              # Decrease the (implicit) input-integer by 1 to make it 0-based
 Ø             # Get the 0-based n'th prime
  [            # Start an infinite loop:
   ₂‰          #  Take the divmod 26
     ˜         #  Flatten the resulting list
      0K       #  And remove any 0s
        Z      #  Get the maximum of the list (without popping)
         27‹   #  If it's smaller than 27:
            #  #   Stop the infinite loop
  }<           # After the loop: decrease all values by 1 to make it 0-based
    A          # Push the lowercase alphabet
     sè        # And index the list of integers into it
               # (after which the resulting character-list is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 169 Bytes

isProbablePrime is only valid for 32 bit integers, but it is correct for every 32 bit integer, so this is a valid solution.

```
(int n)->{int x=-1;for(int i=0;i<n;){x++;if(BigInteger.valueOf(x).isProbablePrime(15))i++;}String r="";while(x>0){x--;int m=x%26;r=(char)(m+97)+r;x=(x-m)/26;}return r;};
```

Comment: I realize now this is basically redundant to the answer by Batscha2k

Comment: [148 bytes](https://tio.run/##RVA7a8MwEN7zK45A4YRj1QltSlGVoVuHpoGOpYPsyI5SSw5nOagE/3ZXjQ2Bu@Fe3@OO6qzS4/5nMPbUkIdjrLlV/sBfTfXmvK40CZgVtWpbeFfGXWYAJvapVIWG7X8J8OnJuAoKjBMITMRmHzNG65U3BWzBgYTBpZvLdUWmy4WR2cKKsiEU5sUJZkq8cfKzqjv9UWKSBMZNu6MmV3mtd2SsxuUjYyZJxMRLcj4fgcImEySxOChiaJPnJ5YQCxLTNKRoZbhbrRm7X60Fad@RAxL9IGZR56nL66hzkntuzB5sdIsjw9c3KDZa9br1@JBlk8mbxevNdTo@YfrMb@u15U3n@Ski@dqh4wUGNt33wx8 "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 135 bytes

```
procedure f(n)
k:=seq()&s:=0&0=k%(i:=2to k)&s+:=1&i=k&s=1&p:=k-1&n-:=1&n=0
t:="";until t[1:1]:=char(97+p%26)&p:=p/26-1&p<0;return t
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BDsIgDIbve4qGZAQyFwGTGdH6IsaD2TASFJAxjU@vTC@e2nzt3362D/79jin0ZpiSgTPzvHIaR3NnnI4aBRXoamY1qhzAFdZolNSio2OpUaNrJfXtDD2KKmskZDv5bK@QD1LLo8b@ckpss25irTo@R@JSdSUVd2KbTJ6Sh1wZP/x53E7WM14BgHmY9ILyX0IRUAKGAM9ks2F2AaTdk0WRtvy7@@NEqtXMz6w0ZTBf/gA)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 27 bytes

`VQ.VhZIP_b=ZbB;p*\a/Z26@GtZ`

Explaination:

```
                            # Implicit Q = eval(input())
                            # Implicit Z = 0
VQ                          # for N in range(Q)
  .VhZ                      #     for b in infinite_range(Z+1)
      IP_b                  #         if is_prime(b)
          =Zb               #             Z = b
             B;             #             break
             p*\a/Z26       # print("a"*Z//26, end="")
                     @GtZ   # 
                            # Implicit print(G[Z-1])
```